# Parallelism in one web request

Tags: python, django, parallel-processing

Our server has a lot if CPUs, and some web requests could be faster if request handlers would do some parallel processing.

Example: Some work needs to be done on N (about 1-20) pictures, to severe one web request.

Caching or doing the stuff before the request comes in is not possible.

What can be done to use several CPUs of the hardware:

- threads: I don't like them
- multiprocessing: Every request needs to start N processes. Many CPU cycles will be lost for starting a new process and importing libraries.
- special (hand made) service, which has N processes ready for processing
- cellery (rabbitMQ): I don't know how big the communication overhead is...
- Other solution?

Platform: Django (Python)

Comment: Well, you already excluded the most common ways - threads ( because you don't like them? seriously? ) and multiprocessing, so good luck with that. :)

Comment: If you want a hammer, try Twisted.

Comment: Why I don't like threads is explained in "cons of threads": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python#answer-3046201

Comment: I'd put the data in a queue (i.e. RabbitMQ) and have a number of worker processes/threads. See http://www.slideshare.net/tarequeh/life-in-a-queue-using-message-queue-with-django

Comment: Some more info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing and celery/django docs: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your second and third alternatives: you do not need to start a new process for every request. This is what [process pools](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html) are for. New processes are created when your app starts up. When you submit a request to the pool, it is automatically queued until a worker is available. The disadvantage is that requests are blocking- if no worker is available at the moment, your user will sit and wait.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [standard library module ***asyncore***](http://docs.python.org/2/library/asyncore.html).

> This module provides the basic infrastructure for writing asynchronous socket service clients and servers.

There is an example for [**how to create a basic HTML client**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/asyncore.html#asyncore-example-basic-http-client).

---

Then there's [***Twisted***](http://twistedmatrix.com), it can do lots and lots of things, which is why it's somewhat daunting. Here is an [**example using its HTTP client**](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/client.html).

---

Twisted "*speaks HTTP*", asyncore does not, *you*'ll have to.

---

Other libraries:

- [**Tornado's httpclient**](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/httpclient.html)
- [**asynchttp**](http://asynchttp.sourceforge.net/)